# Netbeans Jira configuration

Tags: netbeans, jira

I try configure [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) (trial version) connection in Netbeans (8.0.2 Windows 7), but I have got or 405:
[image]

Or:
[image]

Where is problem: in Jira server configuration or in Netbeans (or I just use incorrect url), and how I can resolve it?
Proxy disabled in NB options;

Comment: I have the same issue, Have you somehow figured it out ?

Comment: @PiniCheyni Unfortunately not =( Can You answer on this question if find solution, please?

Comment: If the JIRA version you are connecting to is 7 or higher then the Netbeans JIRA plugin will not work as Atlassian have removed support for the SOAP interface that the plugin was using (see [this announcement](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/soap-and-xml-rpc-api-deprecation-notice) )

Comment: Yupiii! I'm not stupid, it's just unsupported protocol! @DuncanKinnear Thanks. Can You add this comment as post, so that I can mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 6.0 of the JIRA server the SOAP/XML-RPC was deprecated, and in version 7.0 it was finally removed (see [this announcement](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/soap-and-xml-rpc-api-deprecation-notice)). Since the NetBeans JIRA plugin used SOAP to communicate with the JIRA server, this essentially 'broke' the NetBeans JIRA plugin.

Atlassian now only support their REST API for JIRA, so until someone rewrites the JIRA plugin using REST, you cannot integrate NetBeans with JIRA.

Comment: The netbeans Jira plugin does support the REST interface, and has done for years. You can switch in Tools->Options->Team->Jira & select the connector for Jira 5.0+.

Comment: @Ray Thanks so much for this, I never new that was there. We are now back up and running with our ver 6.x JIRA.